# empirical relative frequency

Tags: r, sampling, resampling

I have this histogram:

[image]

I am wondering what i means to find the empirical relative frequency of say salaries < 85000. I understand that empirical frequency is the occurrence int eh data set.

Is this correct:

```
x = our_sample[our_sample$Salaries < 85000, ] # x has 292 rows
result <- 292 / length(our_sample) # our_sample has 500 samples
result
```

I am not sure which functions to use to find this.

Comment: number of salaries less than 85000 / total number of salaries

Comment: You can use the "/" function.

Comment: How do I count them though? All i know is these are the resampled means of the original sample mean. @Sotos

Comment: @Edward could you give an example please?